# Lytebox close/next/previous buttons not displaying

Tags: lytebox

I just downloaded lytebox.  Everything seems to be working, except one feature.  The close/next/previous buttons are not displaying.  They still work, just I can't see them.  I have moved the images folder to the same directory as my lytebox.css and lytebox.js, moved them to another directory, moved the images into the same dir as .css/.js, but nothing seems to get them displayed properly.  I haven't edited any code.  Are there any common reasons why they won't display properly?  I have looked in the lytebox faq, but the suggestion there did not help.  I can display the code if needed, it's just superlong so I don't want to take up too much space.

Answer (score 0):

The path of all images should be located in lytebox.css. Search the code for the image names and you will see them. Then relocate the images or edit the css-file.

Comment: The path looks correct.  There are several different colors, but all have a path of url('images/close_black.png').  My images are all located in a folder that is in the same dir as lytebox.css.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and sorted it by doing this
url('../images/close_black.png')